How to make data(graph) to be exact or similar like the other data(graph)
I want to ask if is it possible to modify the ttime company graph to be exact or similar like ttime ggl graph? The data ttime company is from my company and i want to reshape or modify or anything as long as it can be like ttime ggl that is from google data. I also need to reapply what i do to get the graph similar for the data next day without referring ttime ggl data. graph
For now, i just can clear the outlier for ttime company but how to get the same shape.
